# Intuitive 3D Math Resources

Tags: math, 3d, quaternions, vectormath

I have been trying to find some well presented and explained Vector and Quaternion resources recently to brush up on my 3D skills, and have been having some trouble.

Most of the resources I have found tend skip over the **high-level reason that performing a particular operation is useful,** and dives straight into jargon and proofs that tends to loose my attention rather quickly.

I have found that [better explained](http://betterexplained.com/) has really good explanations of various math topics, however doesn't have anything for Vectors or quaternions.

**Does anyone know of any high level Vector and/or Quaternion tutorials?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get [3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1556229119). It's not a free online tutorial, but I seriously doubt you could find any online tutorial that covers 3D math in such detail while still being very accessible and beginner-friendly. It's got the best coverage of quaternions that I've come across, and it also introduces all the mathematical formulas with a geometric interpretation so that you know how they relate to computer graphics.

Other than that, here's a good basic [Vector Math Tutorial](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html). For Quaternions there's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) and some other resources you could find with google, but they all seem too brief or tied to a certain technology. Again, just buy that book (or alternatively [this one](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/1584502770) which covers more topics but spends less time on the basics).

Comment: I have to echo my support for this wonderful book (3D Math Primer). It's on my shelf and remains my go-to when I have issues.

Comment: Good advise, and i found my work has a copy. I thumbed through the Quaternion section and it was quite good, however I spotted a typo in the cross multiplication formula! Made me laugh.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno about Quaternionssnsns thingys - but here's a really good Vector site:

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/VectorLessons/vectorIndex.html

Comment: This is the most painless introduction I ever read on a subject, highly reccomended

Answer (score 0):

My computer graphics professor posts his [slides on this.](http://www.cs.uncc.edu/~zwartell/ITCS%206120-8120/current/ITCS%206120.htm) This should cover what you would want on vectors and quaternions.

Answer (score 0):

Try 3blue1brown; the guy has a Youtube channel with a whole bunch of topics plus he's a K-12 mathematics teacher. His explanations are really jargon-free and easy to digest, plenty of pictures and some of the best things IMHO are that he doesn't stick solely to voiceovers, he has a live chat so anyone can ask questions, he does live streaming so although he might not sound "professional" all the time it's definitely a very natural and approachable experience.
He has a bunch of videos on quaternions and vectors. I'll include one of each below:

Visualizing Quaternions- 4D Numbers
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg

Vectors - Essence of Linear Algebra
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs

Happy math.